# How do you find the logo code on theme file or where can I find the header theme file?

Tags: headers, code, logo

I am trying to find the header.php file and/or the code for the logo on any theme file. Under appearance- editor section of my website ( www.pithandsubstance.com ) I can only find function.php and style.php files.

Please note : I am new to Wordpress and highly detailed instructions will be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

PS

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Child theme for the Vlog theme. Header file should be in the parent theme file.

The parent theme file name should be Vblog.

> Go to Dashboard --> Appearance --> Editor.

Top (just below the top) of right corner you can find **"Select theme to edit:"** text. There is a select box. Select Vblog from that select box. Then click select button. Then you can find header.php file.